# How to print the name of the file uploaded in react antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am new to react and learning about files. I tried using a variable('filename' in the code) to store the name of the file when the file gets uploaded and print it in the first line of the code shown below but that wasn't working. I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is the basic code I wrote:

```
<Row> File name: {filename} </Row>
<Row>
  <Form.item name="fileupload"> 
    <Upload name="file" maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} accept=".png" beforeUpload={()=>false}>
      <Button type='primary'> Upload </Button>
    </Upload> 
  </Form>
</Row>
```

I want to print the name of the file uploaded in the first line. Am I doing it correctly and if so how do I print the uploaded file name over there?

Comment: In `onChange` handler you get list of files uploaded, you can use it to put the name of the file wherever you want

Comment: @YashJoshi thank you! It is working now with onChange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `onChange` handler you'll get the information of the file that is uploaded.

`handleFileUpload` Function:

```
const handleFileUpload = (info) => {
  console.log(`File name: ${info.file.name}`)
  // Logic of action you want to perform on file upload
}
```

Add `onChange`:

```
<Row> File name: {filename} </Row>
<Row>
  <Form.item name="fileupload"> 
    <Upload name="file" maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} accept=".png" beforeUpload={()=>false} onChange={handleFileUpload} >
      <Button type='primary'> Upload </Button>
    </Upload> 
  </Form>
</Row>
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood it and realized my mistake.